# Transformations to meet heteroscedasticity

Tags: anova, data-transformation, heteroscedasticity

I have a dataset containing angles. They represent the bending angle that a seedling makes to go toward light. I have two factors: treatment and genotype, so I use a two way ANOVA. However, the heteroscedasticity assumption is not filled. I have really low p values for my Bartlett and Levene tests, and my boxplot looks like this:
[image]

So I want to transform my data in order to apply my ANOVA but I don't know which transformation I could use. Do you have any idea? It seems like a transformation would not really help. However, here I am almost only interested in the interaction, and it is really significant, so even if the applications conditions are not met, can I consider the results as significant, as they have very very high p-values? Also, i would like to run a post-hoc test and I am wondering if I could use a Dunn's test where i specify that every group is a combination of the two factors. I know it is for one way ANOVA, but is it problematic if I create those new groups which are combinations of the two factors? I mean that would give me the differences of the interactions right?

Comment: Are you confusing "homoscedasticity" with "heteroscedasticity"? Homoscedasticity means the conditional variance of the response is constant across the distribution of covariates.

Comment: If there is an assumption (read: ideal condition) here, it is of homoscedasticity, not heteroscedasticity. To allow discussion and experiment, two things would help: (1) posting your data (2) explaining the outcome variable in more detail. The axis labels 0 and 100 could be supplemented. If one group varies over about 180 degrees, and another group much less, then the scope for achieving homoscedasticity seems limited.

Comment: Please look at [this very similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/195198/28500) and its answers. I think that your question might be considered a duplicate. If you don't think so, please edit your question to highlight what you think is still unclear. Edit the question rather than adding a comment, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer! sorry I always confuse those two words!

Comment: The roots homo, hetero mean respectively same and different, as in homogeneous, heterogeneous; homosexual, heterosexual.

Comment: Needs a cross-reference to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629844/non-parametric-anova Please don't run two threads that are so close at the same time.

Comment: Okay no problem! To do this, do I just mention that there is a cross reference and paste the link of the other thread in my question?

Comment: My comments already supply cross-references; the larger point is (ideally) not to run two similar threads at once, and the smaller point is that -- if you do -- then you should provide a cross-reference yourself in future.

Answer (score 5):

Monotonic transformation can improve heteroskedasticity when the spread is a function of location (albeit with some sampling noise, naturally). e.g. if the conditional standard deviation is proportional to the conditional mean, then a log-transformation will tend to give nearly-constant variance. More generally, see the Wikipedia article [Variance-stabilizing transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-stabilizing_transformation)

Here's an example of the kind of appearance where a transformation helps -- that is, where the spread (sd, IQR, etc) changes like it was some smooth function of the location (mean, median etc):

[image: display consisting of 3 subplots. 1. Boxplot of 3 groups with IQR increasing as the median increases. 2. Plot of IQR vs median, so the functional relationship is more explicit. 3. Boxplot of 3 groups after an approximately variance stabilizing transformation, with much more similar spreads]

No transformation of the response variable will do much to "fix" the impression of heteroskedasticity if you have larger and smaller spreads at essentially identical locations --

[image: boxplots of response (angles) for 6 groups (2 treatments x 3 genotypes) subplots]
(... note that for each of the two large spreads, there's a smaller spread with a similar location
{plot is from the original [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/629805/805) by [Marius Audenis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/399436/marius-audenis)} )

With no particularly clear "functional" pattern of spread-vs-mean, there would be no variance-stabilizing transform.

You would be able to find one that would improve things a little (spreading out more at the largest angles and compressing the most negative ones) but I don't think that's likely to be especially helpful overall without straying well outside the usual simple transformation (indeed hunting for one based on the same data you want to use in a hypothesis test will impact the properties of your inference and it won't help the changing spread all that much anyway).

A second (arguably small) issue in that case is that "typical" transformation-families (like Box-Cox) assume positive data. In the boxplot above, lower-median-groups have values either side of zero.

Comment: Thank you! But then if a transformation could not really help, what do I do? Can I just analyse my data like that and mention that heteroskedasticity is not fixed? Or is there any other solution like a non parametric test? Also I forgot to mention but my data is not balanced so maybe that also plays a role.

Comment: I think that's a question where the issues are considerably more involved than suitable for  a brief reply in a comment, and one in which people will likely have a range of thoughts about what might be best in different circumstances. Perhaps it would be a good thing to ask as a new question (including the part about unbalanced data).